# Pivot with Markers as Muticolored Circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create in d3 a chart that looks like this:

[image]

I am not even sure what kind of chart this would be in D3. Its basically a bar chart, but each dot represents a unique entity. The color represents its score.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. An example would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, this is a pictogram. Very easy to build in Tableau, as I see you did here, but not that easy with D3.

Have a look at this example (they provide the code) and see if you can understand how they did it:

http://nandayadav.github.io/nfldrafts_visualization/